# Caro-Kann Bronstein-Larsen Variation For Black

Tags: opening, caro-kann

Any good references (books/videos/tutorials) for this variation?

```
[fen ""]
[StartFlipped "1"]

1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nf6 5.Nxf6+ gxf6
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes there are, but I advise you not to play it. The plan with `g3` + `Bg2` offers White an advantage, if memory serves...

Comment: I actually prefer this variation to the "3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Bf5 5. Ng3" and "3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Nd7" variations. With the former, I am afraid to castle kingside because I could not stop White's kingside pawn storm and when castling queenside, I couldn't think of good plans for Black to play actively. With the latter, the game can be opened by white quickly. I am afraid of open games, I only like closed or semi-closed games, so the Bronstein-Larsen variation seems to be a semi-closed one.

Comment: *3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Bf5 5. Ng3* is quite solid, I would go that way. It offers easy equality, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 2):

If you read Danish there's Bent Larsen's *Solide åbninger* (Solid openings) from 1980.

[image]

It is a repertoire book for beginners (white and black) and suggests the line you inquire about as the defense against `1. e4`.

Comment: Thanks Dag Oskar Madsen, but unfortunately I don't read Danish.